# Selenium ChromeDriver use already open browser

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

Help, please, dv question Selenium ChromeDriver.
Can I work in an already open Chrome browser? Or is it possible to open a new tab in an already open Chrome browser and work in it?

Comment: I think only if that existing browser was already launched via selenium where you can use webdriver remote to connect.

Comment: That is, it means that if you open the browser once through Selenium, then you can apply a macro many times before it is closed?

Comment: Yes you can do that although that is not what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe this is possible.

They go to reasonable lengths to make Chrome display that it is being controlled by test software and presumably attaching to an existing browser window would create a vector for people to highjack the browser of unwitting users.